# How to save data included report?

Tags: android, save

I want to keep an array of information like: Date: 11/20/2017, Time: 1:39 PM Category: Clothing, subcategory: shirt and price $ 9.90. And each time to insert more arrays through the app.

I thought of using sharedpreferences but I could only insert 2 types of information. And that limits me in terms of time, date, category. I can only insert a price and sub-category

Comment: You most likely need to use a database.

Comment: You can use serialization to save your array objects onto the device.
This gives you the opportunity to retrieve it whenever as well as update it.

Comment: and if i just want to save only Key, value, Date, Time? i Have to Database